# Has IQueryable provider to preserve order?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I want to create a custom `IQueryable` provider.

Has my `IQueryable` implementation to preserve the order of the source elements?

For exemple, can `(new [] { 1, 2, 3 }).AsMyQueriable().Select(x => x).ToArray()` return `3, 2, 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, your queryable can do whatever it feels like.  As `IQueryable` is an interface, there is no constructor and so there is no contract you must follow in this regard -- a queryable is just a thing that can be queried via some specific methods, and its beginning state is not something covered as part of the interface contract.  Your extension method's documentation, however, should clearly indicate whether the order of the input sequence is retained by the returned `IQueryable` object.

Of course, if someone calls `.OrderBy()` on an instance of your queryable, it would be expected that you reorder the elements accordingly.  But, if the developer does not call `.OrderBy()` then you are free to return the elements in whatever order you would like.

Comment: In this case, what would be the "expected behavior" of the _Reverse_ method?

Comment: @CédricBignon Not all providers have an implementation for all methods.  It might just throw an exception, or ignore it and return the items in the order that it feels like anyway, unless it is called after an `OrderBy`.

Comment: Sorry, but how constructor relates with contract?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan If interfaces had constructors (which would be silly) then the documentation could specify behaviors that the constructor would be expected to implement.  Since this is not the case, there is no contract that says that "a method that constructs an object implementing `IQueryable` from a sequence is expected to maintain the order of the items in that sequence."

Comment: Contract only defines precondition and postcondition (and invariant of object in case of class). It is not related with have the class/interface ctor or not.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan You are saying the same thing I am, only in different terms.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If anyone using your provider needs to access the elements in a particular order, they can just use [`IQueryable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549264.aspx) instead.